Execute SQL using Spark - BigQuery in Databricks
In databricks, I have a spark session configured with big query connection.
I have a complex sql to be executed( with create tables and merge statements) and persisted in bigQuery.
I want to achieve it without using
df = spark.read.format("bigquery") \
  .option("table",<table-name>) \
  .option("project", <project-id>) 
  .option("query", my_complex_query)

I have tried using sparl.sql(complex_query) but it is saying table not found. After looking through some examples, it is working only when we create views (by splitting the query) for the tables involved in the query - using above spark.read.
I don't want to create views manually as I have many queries to be run and I can't modify each one of them.
Is there a way to just execute the query + persist and exit?
I tried adding spark.sql.defaultCatalog and spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.defaultDatabase in spark config, but it didn't workout - still cried that table not found.
Expectation was to execute sql. I just want to use spark as a proxy on databricks for big query
